# Using Magnet Technology to Make a Rotating Space Station?

Tags: science-based, electromagnetism, artificial-gravity

For an artificial gravity ring station, could you make a central hub, using similar magnet technology used to levitate magnet trains here on earth, to reduce the amount of mass rotating? My thoughts on a configuration are; a central hub, about the size of an SUV, with magnets within it, and it is rotating using thrusters. The ring rests about 100 yards from the hub (91.4 Meters) and spins along with the hub. How much would this cost, approximately, and what would be some problems with this design?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? This is a really expensive and complicated design, but it's not clear to me what it's supposed to accomplish.

Comment: I don't see any point to doing this in space, but if you wanted an environment with artificial Earth-like gravity for a colony on a body with significantly lower gravity like the moon or mars, something like a circular maglev track might be a good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The central hub in this idea is pointless, and you can't build this very large without very strong ring material**.

Basically, a ring space habitat would be made with spokes so that it doesn't distort under the very many stresses it's under.  These include:

- Thermal expansion due to uneven heating as it moves in/out of the sun
- Rotation itself, which will induce stresses unless everything is 100% evenly distributed
- The space environment, which sucks for just about anything we've ever made and will eventually degrade things

So there is no real reason to have the central hub without the spokes.  If you could do away with the spokes, what's the point of the hub?  Once the ring starts rotating it will continue to do so, perhaps with minor input from thrusters if you're near enough an atmosphere to induce some kind of drag.  Magnets wouldn't be required to keep it spinning because it would just...keep spinning.

The only reason I can think of to have it is to stop or modify its rotation.  However, if it's supposed to operate like this then unfortunately it won't work.  Momentum is conserved.  As a result, if you are trying to modify the rotation of the ring, then you will have to dump that momentum into something (the hub, basically) and then eventually dump THAT momentum out using some other means.  Thrusters are the obvious choice for this, but if your space habitat is near enough a strong magnetic field and the speed of the change isn't important you can use [magnetic torquers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetorquer) to do that.  But if you're going to dump into an external magnetic field anyway, why not just do away with a magnetized hub and put magnets all around your habitat?

Cost is practically impossible to gauge because the technology would have to be developed.  If you assume that launch costs are the same as now, you're looking at **at least** $5000/kg just to get the mass to orbit, but that ignores the actual costs of building and delivering and assembling this thing.

Comment: A stationary central hub isn't pointless: for one obvious advantage, it makes it a lot easier to dock incoming spacecraft.

Answer (score 1):

[Maglev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maglev) -- where things like trains are levitated above a track to reduce eliminate friction with the track, works simply by having magnetic fields that repel each other.

To do this "for free" (without electromagnets and the mass-increasing costs of electricity generation that this brings), you would have to use fixed magnets.  This is certainly possible (but expensive) on Earth, as you have a different force, gravity, working to keep things in place despite the magnetic field's desire to make things very unstable.

In space, fixed magnets aligned the right way to do maglev will just repel each other or (more likely and worse), will flip the parts of your station around so that they're now attracting each other.  Any system to counteract this tendency to flip or to infinitely repel will always be heavier than just a steel scaffolding between your parts, and will be complex, thus difficult to maintain.

Also, if your goal is to attract the parts of your station... steel bolts work better than magnets, and weigh about the same.

There is a concept of [diamagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism) levitation: It keeps an object a fixed distance from a magnetic field.  However, this is incredibly weak in most materials; the materials that show significant amounts of diamagnetism at room temperature are still incredibly weak... and the whole point of a circular space station with any sort of hub is to have artificial gravity in the ring. That means your station will be exerting constance forces against the hub, and these forces are absolutely certain to be stronger than diamagnetic levitation.

Any sci-fi setting where people care about how expensive it is to get something to orbit will not have the technology to "levitate" parts of their space station when under force.

If you want artificial gravity with a ring-like station, use scaffolds, tethers, and spokes.

Answer (score 1):

The reduction in mass can be achieved without the use of magnets. The reason we use maglev trains here on earth is to reduce *friction* between the train and the rails. In space, there's no friction to worry about, so there's no need for your wheel to be attached to a central hub unless you want it to be. A space station that is nothing but a rotating ring is entirely feasible.

Answer (score 1):

This is plausible, but not with this design.

If the ultimate goal is to have a stationary hub with rotating habitat ring, this may work. Existing designs of rotating space stations usually include rotating hub firmly attached to the ring rather than a stationary "axle" hub.

The big problem with the stationary hub is reliability of moving large parts of the station with respect to each other. If the system gets jammed, the result can be catastrophic. Assuming current aerospace sturdiness of construction, the spokes would simply break apart. If we want the station to rotate together after the jam, sturdiness has to be increased by a factor of 10, and still the effect of a sudden "jerk" would be damaging to the interior of the station.

Here comes maglev to the rescue. First, a chance of jamming is lower because there is no contacting moving parts. Second, if the maglev system fails, central hub can execute an emergency maneuver of completely separating itself from the rotating ring. Overall design becomes considerably safe.

The issue with the original design seems to be that the ring was expected to rotate at the distance from central hub - but there is no practical way of keeping it up there using magnetic force. Maglev approach, by contrast, requires a relatively short distance which can be controlled with precision. Also, maglev approach allows energy transfer between the ring and the hub, which would be much more problematic with a "distant ring" design.

However, there is still an issue with material and personnel transfer between the ring and the hub. Without very sophisticated solutions that's going to be a spacewalk. One sophisticated solution can be a coaxial transfer gondola. To go from the hub to the ring, an astronaut would enter a pressurized gondola which is docked to the hub. Then, gondola undocks from the hub and starts rotating (using its own maglev railway on the inner side of rotating ring), matching the speed of the ring. Next, gondola's outer size docks to the ring, and astronaut can move to the ring.

And let me stress again that this makes sense only if we really want our hub to be stationary.